# Is "one" always a quantity if not a pronoun?

Tags: word-choice

In medical transcription we are required to type all numbers as digits (unless beginning a sentence). Some phrases include the word "one," such as, "I will get around to it 1 of these days," "...on multiple occasions.  The most recent 1...," "At 1 point..."

Is "one" in these examples a true quantity?

It just feels like it should be spelled out, but in discussing this with others, I could not come up with any rules to back up my instinct.  In the common phrase, such as "one of these days," the whole phrase can be replaced with something else, like, "eventually."  In the second example, the word behaves like a pronoun, where "one" replaces "occasion."  "At one point," could be changed without changing the meaning to "at some point."  Is my point valid?

Medical transcriptionists by nature tend to be picky about wording, so I imagine there are others that would be interested in this answer.

Comment: Hello and welcome to EL&U. This is a good question. There are phrases where it's definitely not a pronoun and not a quantity - e.g. "at one with ...". However, in your examples, it *is* a quantity of sorts, just not the sort that translates particularly well to digits. I agree with your instinct on this, though I don't have enough to explain why.

Comment: Pure drivel. The fault belongs to whoever in your organisation said “…type all numbers as digits (unless beginning a sentence)”.

Who believes “… beginning a sentence” makes a difference, speak up now.

“Medical transcription” generally follows no such rule, as you will find if you ask colleagues in other institutions.

General English suggests numbers up to 9 or 10; sometimes 11 be spelt out, then all higher numbers should use only digits… even there, notice the difference among 9, 10 and 11.

“Medical transcription” has no reason to follow anything other than general use in English.

Comment: It can be a quality.

Comment: '1 of these days' looks non-standard, textspeak. I'd go with regarding 'one of these days' as an idiom, a single lexeme as you suggest. And idioms resist variation in form (though it's far from unknown). The idiom contains the orthographic word _one_ not the numeral. The guidelines should probably restrict the mandatory use of numerals to when the numeral usage is obvious (counting or measures); imagine if one had to write 'The patient is a resident of 7 Sisters, London'.

Comment: Merriam-Webster says "one" is an adjective meaning "being an unknown, undetermined, or unspecified unit or thing" in constructions such as "one day", and "one of these days" is I imagine the same.

Comment: I believe 1 argue that the transcriptionist's rules are a bit silly. You'll find attorneys have habits when writing numbers in contracts, but you wouldn't find one (1) who enforces a single rule in all situations.

Comment: Jimm101 is quite right. 1 must decide for 1self when it gets ludicrous.

Comment: One of these days: one is not a digit there. Take 1 pill with water after a meal. There, it is a digit.

Comment: *It was just one of those things / Just one of those crazy flings /
One of those bells that now and then rings /
Just one of those things* — Nelson Riddle

Comment: It's just a different way to spell _one_. It has no effect on grammar, nor does grammar have any effect on spelling. There's no question here.

Answer (score 1):

In the cases you've given it's more of an idiom than a true quantity, and one that can probably be replaced in most cases with different phrasing that doesn't run into this issue. *But* if there is a guideline that says "a number is a number and this is how we write it" you don't really have an argument to use one in place of 1 at any stage because the rule says there's no difference.

Answer (score 0):

**One** is also a noun: *"You have omitted a one in that number. It should be 49217, not 4927"*

"She is the one I love."

"He's a right one, he is!"

"I am at one with John's answer."

Answer (score -1):

"One" can be an *ordinal number*.  Bachelor number *one*, bachelor number two, bachelor number three.  Of course, one could just as well say bachelor A, bachelor B, bachelor C, so "one" (or even "number one") isn't serving as a quantity, but rather as an [*ordinal number*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ordinal%20number):

> a number designating the place (such as first, second, or third)
>   occupied by an item in an ordered sequence

Comment: it's not an ordinal number just because it plays a rôle in an ordering expression